# Explanation as to why $G/N$ = $<gN>$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was hoping that someone could help explain to me how we know that $G$/$N$ is a collection of the left-cosets and can be written as $G/N$ = $< gN >$.

Comment: The quotient group $G/N$ is defined for $N\lhd G$. When $N\lhd G$, the left and right cosets coincide (i.e., $gN=Ng~\forall~g\in G$). So, the set of all left cosets and the set of all right cosets are the same and this set along with the operation $(aN)(bN)=(ab)N$ is defined as the quotient group $G/N$.

Comment: **Note:** $N\lhd G$ denotes that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: So because $gN$ = $Ng$, could we also say that $G/N$ = $< Ng >$?

Comment: If by $<Ng>$, you mean the set $\{Ng\mid g\in G\}$, then yes.

Comment: Yes. Thank you :)

Comment: What's the context of this question? If $G/N = \langle gN \rangle$ then $G/N$ is cyclic. This isn't true in general.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas But that isn't what $\langle Ng \rangle$ means,so you are not being very helpful.